# Recompiled APK throws error "This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement"

Tags: apk, 64-bit, apktool

I have the situation that I have an old APK file without my source code anymore. Until now it was no problem to install the APK manually and use it. Since I needed to install a work profile on my phone the security settings changed and I only can use signed apps from the Google Play Store.

Therefore my goal is to get the app to the Play Console - at least as a internal testing version.

My steps:

1. I decompiled the APK with Apktool

```
apktool d "myapp.apk" -o "myapp.apk-decompiled"
```

2. Then I adapted the AndroidManifest.xml to meet the current Google Play Console requirements with regards to API level and Target SDK.
3. Used apktool to created the updated APK file

```
apktool b "myapp.apk-decompiled" --use-aapt2 -o "myapp-modified.apk"
```

4. Next I used uber-apk-signer in order to sigh the app with my valid keystore file from another app that I published already in the Play Store.

```
java -jar uber-apk-signer-1.3.0.jar -a ./myapp-modified.apk --ks ~/Dev/Keystore/upload-keystore.jks --ksAlias myalias
```

5. Eventually I used a converter (android app) to get the bundle file (aab) from the APK

Now, when I try to create a release for internal testing in the Google Play Console I can upload the aab-file just fine, but when I progress to the next step, unfortunately 1 error remains that prevents me to release my app.
Error: "This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code"

My assumption is that it is linked somehow to libraries that are included in the APK.

Directory structure:
lib
|-- armeabi
|-- armeabi-v7a
|-- x86

I've read lots of solutions by adapting the gradle file. As I need to decompile the APK file, I have no gradle file that I can edit.

Any hints if that is possible at all?

**Update #1:**
Meanwhile I found the correct 64bit lib files and added them to the lib directory. But still no luck once I recompiled the app with apktool

lib
|-- armeabi
|-- armeabi-v7a
|-- x86
|-- x86_64

Comment: Your app is 32bit only and you can noch change that as you would require to find all used libraries in exactly the same versions in arm64 code. Google does not allow non-64 bit apps, so Play Console is not an option for that app. Also just increasing targetSDK versions will also change code behavior, thus most likely the app wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: Thx Robert. Let's say I found the x64 libs (it's the portsip lib). Do you know how this can be added at all to the apk?
I added the x86_64 directory to the lib-directory and re-compiled the app with the apktool. When I analyze the app in Android studio, it still just shows armeabi, armeabi-v7a and x86, but not x86_64

Comment: Are you sure you analyze the correct APK? apktool does not modify the original APK file, instead it generates a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77891293/150978

Comment: I was not specific enough regarding the error:
I managed to generate the apk with the additional libs. But when I upload it into Google Play Console I still get the 64bit-incompatibility error