# Apktool recompile options

Tags: apktool

I want to find out a solution for a little issue I have when using apktool I decompile an apk no issues with that, `apktool d name.apk` an original folder is created with the original AndroidManifest.xml and the META-INF folder.

The problem is when I try to do a cosmetic change, for example changing the "apk name" on the AndroidManifest.xml file but later when I recompile the apk (`apktool b -c name.apk`) forcing apktool to copy the META-INF then the original AndroidManifest.xml file is copy as well obviously without the cosmetic changes I did. Any solution? thank you!

```
apktool d name.apk - apktool b -c name
```

Comment: @Robert Im using the correct apk, the things is that I just want to change the apk label name, when decompile with apktool it create a folder with the original Androidmanifest and the META-INF, ok now I modify the apk label correctly but when recompile it back I need that META-INF folder to be add to the build for that I use apktool b -c whatever name but that also copy the original file of Androidmanifest that means that the resulting apk in dist folder do not have the modified Androidmanifest –

Comment: Then why do you use the `-c` option - just build the APK without.

Comment: @Robert because if I do not use the -c command when recompiling the apk it will not contain the META-INF data and this causes the apk not to work when it is installed

Comment: Does the APK does not work because the signature has changed or because there are additional files in META-INF which are required by the APK? If it is the signature you have a bigger problem, because if you keep the old signature you can by definition not modify anything. Otherwise simply remove the `-c` option and add the necessary files manually after rebuilding the APK using a ZIP tool.

Comment: @Robert Uuhmm! It had not occurred to me, I have always thought that it is because the apk needed the additional META-INF files, I am going to try your suggestion and install them manually. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Robert,One thing, how can we know if the apk does not work because of the signature change or because it is missing META-INF files? Thank you so much.

Comment: I would use the original APK and just resign it using apksigner. If it works you know that the signature is not a problem.

Comment: @Robert nothing, there is no way.  I have signed the original APK without changing anything and it works without problem so I rule out it being a signing problem.  As soon as I modify the name of the "app label" in the Androidmanifest and compile the APK again with "apktool b name.apk" the installation does not work.  I already think I'm going to give up.

Comment: The installation does not work? Have you zipaligned and signed the rebuilt APK? Also make sure that the app is not already installed on the phone. Install it via adb and you will get an error message why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Robert There is no way, these are my steps so far:
1. Apktool d name.apk
2. Edit AndroidManifest.xml to change the label name
3. Save changes in AndroidManifest.xml
4. Apktool b (apk) name
5. Zipaling/sign with apksigner
6. Install resulting apk with adb
7. Success to install on the device
8. Add obb files
8. Run APK but NOT WORK

I think the problem is when I edit the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Robert,Hello, I think the problem is something else. I try to modify the apk label name no matter where you modify it, in the AndroidManifest.xml or in the Strings.xml, just by deleting one character from the original name, the apk does not run once reinstalled. Do you think there is any order in the apk that prohibits changing the label name? THX

Answer (score 0):

First, if you only want to modify resources, I would stringly recommend to use the `--no-src` option when decompiling an APK. This will save you a lot of time and disk space as well as prevent potential problems when rebuilding the APK.

App names are usually not loaded from `AndroidManifest.xml` because it only contains one non-localized version.

Better search for the app name in the localized strings. So my guess is that recompile works but the outcome is different than you expect as Android simply ignores your modified attribute.

If you want to make sure a modification `AndroidManifest.xml` was recompiled into the APK, open the rebuilt APK in [Jadx-Gui](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) and look if the modification is visible or not.

Comment: What I want to change is the name with which the apk is displayed once installed, I see this name in the Androidmanifest file, in my case I want to remove a series of Chinese characters that appear in the name of the installed application

Comment: @FranAlvarado Make sure you are using the correct APK that contains the changes. See my answer here where apktool creates by default the rebuilt APK file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77891293/150978

Comment: Im using the correct apk, the things is that I just want to change the apk label name, when decompile with apktool it create a folder with the original Androidmanifest and the META-INF, ok now I modify the apk label correctly but when recompile it back I need that META-INF folder to be add to the build for that I use apktool b -c whatever name but that also copy the original file of Androidmanifest that means that the resulting apk in dist folder do not have the modified Androidmanifest